# Who is the girl sleeping besides Bruce Wayne when he wakes up from his nightmare?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, batman-v-superman-dawn-of-justice

In the movie Batman vs Superman, at the end of the first nightmare we see him have, Bruce Wayne wakes up in his bed and there is a girl sleeping besides him. There was no reference to her before or after that scene. I thought the only people that stay in the house are Bruce Wayne and Alfred. Who is this girl/lady Bruce Wayne slept with?

Comment: @mido I didn't downvote, but I'm guessing that the downvoters consider it self-evident that there is no indication of any information about her anywhere in the film.

Comment: She just might be another beautiful girl Batman uses to wear the mask of Bruce Wayne.

Comment: Bruce Wayne likes to get around with the ladies. Maybe that was his date for an event the night before.

Comment: @recognizer It's not self-evident who the girl is. In fact I had the same question. I joked with a friend that the naked body next to Batfleck is Alfred, as evidenced by the fact he appears in the very next scene (though fully clothed) :P

Comment: @AndresF. What I'm saying: It is self-evident that there's no answer to this question. I believe we could pore over every frame of the film, and not find anything to support any conclusive answer. All we can say is it's not Lois or Diana :)

Comment: @recognizer Or Alfred? :(

Comment: @recognizer it may be "self-evident" that there is no information about this in the film (I agree). But the beauty and the purpose of this site is that you ask that question and someone might have a consistent in-universe answer form other canon sources like the novelization of the movie, the movie script, media interviews with the director and similar sources. I was wondering the same too, just because this movie has been so loaded with "easter eggs" and other comic references, that the identity of that lady could have been a relevant DC name. It's sad seems so many "fast-drawing" downvoters

Comment: Scene needed a pair of cat ears on the floor.

Comment: I believe it to be Rashontae Wawrzyniak. She's credited as "[Beautiful Woman](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm6541659/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t55)" on IMDB, seems to have no discernible part in the film and her shoulders are very angular and her arms are very slender, matching the girl on the bed

Comment: Why are all of you arguing with recognizer?  He stated that he didn't downvote, and was just speculating about what he thought the probable motivation was.  Arguing with someone who didn't down-vote over a downvote seems pointless.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Though the movies often neglect this Bruce Wayne maintains an image of a millionaire playboy to avoid suspicion. It's a common thing for Bruce to have girls around to keep the gossip going.

[image]

Not sure why she was in his bed though as in the comics Bruce only pretends to sleep around and drink.

[image]

Though it's worth mentioning that in the film he does drink for real so it's reasonable to assume that he sleeps around for real.

So to answer your question, no one important. She's just there to maintain the illusion.

Comment: Ok. Removed the downvote...But I would accept this answer only if there is some comic book reference...(until then its just an assumption)

Comment: @Crusaderpyro this is a scene from Batman Year One in which he hires a prostitute to just hang around while he talks to James Gordon and his wife. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cbZ7W2SkAR8

Comment: Why does it have to be to maintain an illusion?  Maybe he just really is a playboy.

Comment: It's not shown in the comic, but in the animated movie the girl actually can speak English; she calls Bruce and Alfred weird, and former replies that she has nothing to complain for, since she made 2 or 4 thousand dollars out of it.

Answer (score -4):

I believe it is Talia, who is supposed to give birth to Bruce's son, Damian Wayne

Answer (score -6):

Hhhhmmm, lets see. He knew about her before  Ra's a ghoul and Zack. Its Natalia I think but Batman does sleep around so who know because Alfred mentioned to Brice about a next generation of Wayne.